# In $Δ ABC,\;AB=AC$ and $\measuredangle CAB=90^o,\;M$ and $N$ are points on hypotenuse $BC$ with $BM^2+CN^2=MN^2$. Prove $\measuredangle MAN=45^o$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

Let $ABC$ be a triangle in which $AB = AC$ and $|\angle CAB| = 90^{\circ}$. Suppose $M$ and $N$ are points on the hypotenuse $BC$ such that $BM^2 + CN^2 = MN^2$. Prove that $|\angle MAN| = 45^{\circ}$.
[image]

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?

Comment: Too much to imagine please a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\angle BAM=\alpha, \angle CAN=\beta, BM=x\sqrt{2},CN=y\sqrt{2}$.  We want to check that $\tan(\alpha+\beta)=1$.
The given formula is that $x^2+y^2=(1-x-y)^2$, or $1-2x-2y+2xy=0$.
$$\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}\\
=\frac{\frac x{1-x}+\frac y{1-y}}{1-\frac{xy}{(1-x)(1-y)}}\\
=\frac{x-xy+y-xy}{1-x-y}=\frac{1-x-y}{1-x-y}$$

Comment: Where did the $-2xy$ go? I'm stuck on figuring that out right now.

Comment: Given $1-2x-2y+2xy$, therefore $1-x-y=x+y-2xy$

Answer (score 0):

As sides AB=AC and angle BAC is 90 the triangle is a right angle isosceles triangle.

as
$$BM^2+CN^2=MN^2$$
The side BM and CN can be folded to outside to join.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt9tQ.png)

The sides will join and give a right triangle. the line MA and AN will give a polygon.With the help of this you may prove that the Angle MAN is 45.
This condition is only possible if BM=NC.

Take points close to each other you will find it is not possible

Comment: see the image in the ans

Answer (score 0):

Assume $$∠MAN ≠ 45° \tag1$$  Let $CN’ = 0, BM’ = BC/2$, so $$CN’^2 + BM’^2 = M’N’^2 \tag2$$

Since $∠CAB = 90°, BM’ = CM’ = N’M’$, so $∠M’AN’ = 45°$.

Hence $(1)$ cannot be true if condition $(2)$ is to be met (*Reductio ad absurdum*).

[image]

Comment: Click "enter image description here" to view image. 
-wz01460

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score -1):

Synthetic proof:

Construction:
Drop perpendiculars MD and NE on to the side AB, and MF and NG on to the side AC. Please refer [fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfe9x.jpg). Join SA.

It is easy to see that the trinagles BDM , MSN and NGC thus formed are all similar to the given triangle ABC. From data, AB = AC. Therefore all the triangles BDM , MSN and NGC are also isosceles right angled triangles with,

$BD = DM = p$

$MS = SN = q$

$NG = GC = r$

From Pythagoras theorem,we have

$BM^2 = 2p^2$

$CN^2 = 2r^2$

$MN^2 = 2q^2$

But from data, we have

$BM^2 + CN^2 = MN^2$

$=>2p^2 + 2r^2 = 2q^2$

$=>p^2 + r^2 = q^2$ ------ 1

$MDAF$ and $NSFG$ are rectangles.------ from construction. (refer [fig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmVp2.jpg))

Therefore,

$MD = AF = p$  and  $NG = SF = r ------- 2$

In right angled triangle AFS,

$AF^2 + SF^2 = AS^2$
  => AS = q ------------- From 1 and 2.

=> In triangle MAN , MS = SN = AS = q  which means S is the circumcentre of triangle MAN. Chord MN subtends a right angle at S ( MSN is similar to right angled triangle ABC). Therefore on the circumference , i.e, at A (the circumcircle of MAN passes through A!) it subtends 45 degrees.  QED

Please comment.

Answer (score -3):

Without loss of generality, assume $BC=1$. Let $BM=x$ and $CN=y$, so $MN=1-x-y$. Then it is given that $x^2+y^2=(1-x-y)^2$. However, there is an infinite number of possibile pairs $(x,y)$ with $0<x,y<\frac{1}{2}$ such that $x^2+y^2=(1-x-y)^2$. Only 1 choice of $(x,y)$ leads to $\angle MAN=45$ degrees. In other words, you can not prove it.

Comment: To the persons who downvoted my answer, I am curious what is wrong with it. I checked my reasoning and even drew some neat pictures, but I can't find what's wrong. Could you elaborate?

Comment: How did you reason that only $1$ choice of $x$ and $y$ yields the result?

Comment: $\angle MAN=45\ \iff\ x=y$. So $BM=CN=x$, $MN=1-2x$ and it is given that $x^2+x^2=(1-2x)^2$. This has solutions $x=1\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, of which only $x=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ lies within $(0,\frac{1}{2})$, such that $BM=CN=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is indeed **the only** choice of $x$ and $y$ that yields the result. So again, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I see. But do not forget that you assumed $BC = 1$.

Comment: I did no such thing. Have you really tried to understand my answer? I mean draw it, follow the arguments step by step. I did that a number of times and could find no faulty step.

Comment: Comment previously stated "you assumed $MN=1$". Anyway, I assumed that _without loss of generality_. If you think that can not be done, please tell me why. It is basically preserving the ratios between all lengths, but making computations easier...

Comment: I'll present a counterexample tomorrow, i.e. triangle $ABC$ such that: $AB=BC$, $\angle CAB=90$, $BM^2+CN^2=MN^2$ and $\angle MAN\not=45$. But now, it is dinner time, adieu :)

Comment: Most of your work is correct, but it is based on an error at the start.  $\angle MAN=45$ does not imply $x=y$.  If $\angle BAM=40,\angle MAN=45,\angle NAC=5$ then $x\neq y$

Comment: @Michael, you are completely right. I stand corrected, thank you.